# Is the set of matrices over GL(2, $\mathbb{Q}^+$) a group? If yes, how to show the inverse law holds for the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

The question in the book is:
[image]
I need only (c.)

Answer in the solution manual: $G_3$ is a group.

What I've already proved: Closure, associated & Identity properties are satisfied for the set $G_3$.
But I can't show: Inverse property holds or not!
What I've done so far:
Let, $ A \in G_3 $ such that, $$ A = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) $$
Then, $ A^{-1}  = \frac{1}{ad-bc} \cdot \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} d & -b  \\  -c & a \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)
$
Since, -b, -c is negative rational number, then $ A^{-1} \notin G_3 $
Hence, $ G_3 $ doesn't satisfy inverse property. So, $G_3$ isn't a group.

Is this correct? Please clarify.

Comment: Looks like you are right and the book is wrong, unless the notation doesn't mean positive numbers.

Comment: Maybe the book means $GL_2(\mathbb Q)^+$, the group of 2x2 matrices with positive determinant?

Comment: Thank you @hunter

Comment: (I agree with @KentaS that this is most likely what the book means.)

Comment: Please look at the question, I've updated it.

Comment: Oh yeah, c is not a group, the solution manual is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @hunter for your help!

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.